# Error al recibir variables por Método POST en una clase con PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy recibiendo información de un formulario, la cual quiero dar de alta mediante un formulario con PHP; asigno los valores a unas propiedades que tengo declaradas dentro de una clase Llamada Alta la cual hereda de Conecta; pero obtengo el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\Altas.php on line 7

El código de mi clase es el siguiente

```
require 'Conexion.php';

class Altas extends Conecta
{
    public $name = $_POST["name"];
    public $mail = $_POST["email"];
    public $biography = $_POST["biography"];
    public $degree = $_POST["degree"];

    public function altaUser($name, $mail, $biography, $degree)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->biography = $biography;
        $this->degree = $degree;

        $stmt = parent::$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles(name, email, biography, degree) VALUES(:name, :mail, :biography, :degree)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $this->mail);
        $stmt->bindParam(":biography", $this->biography);
        $stmt->bindParam(":degree", $this->degree);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: No deberías recibir datos de esta manera, directamente en la clase, deberías utilizar un intermediario y pasar los datos en el constructor de la clase.

Comment: dame un ejemplo @YoAlbert me encuentro un tanto confundido por favor

Comment: Redactare una respuesta conforme a esto.

Comment: Por qué o para qué inicializas las variables con POST ? no estoy del todo seguro, pero no puedes inicializar una variable desde la clase con un valor no estático, es decir dentro de los métodos lo podrías hacer, pero en el public no, si se puede, esta clase solo sirve si viene de un POST dado que de lo contrario tronaría al no encontrar la variable, de todos modos estás sobreescribiendo las variables en tu método, entonces, no le encuentro mucho sentido

Comment: @Sr1871 por que las estoy intentando recibir directo de un formulario que las envia por ese método

Comment: pero el método es el de altaUser no es así? tú las inicializas fuera del método con un varlo dinámico, por qué no tratar de inicializarlas dentro del método con el POST? de no ser así, creo que entonces no estoy entendiendo muy bien la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías tener un intermediario entre tu clase y tu `submit` ya que de la manera que lo estas haciendo no es la correcta, aparte de que no seria escalable tu código, podría presentar fallos, mi propuesta es la siguiente;

creas un archivo nomabrado `altas_controller.php` este recibira tu submit y incluirá tu archivo con la clase altas `Altas.php`;

`altas_controller.php`

```
<?php

require("altas.php");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$mail = $_POST["email"];
$biography = $_POST["biography"];
$degree = $_POST["degree"];

//Instanciamos tu clase

$nueva_alta = new Alta($name,$mail,$biography ,$degree);
$nueva_alta->altaUser();
```

archivo `altas.php` le haremos una modificación para agregar un constructor;

```
require 'Conexion.php';

class Altas extends Conecta
{
   //ahora todos tus propiedades son privadas
    private $name;
    private $mail;
    private $biography;
    private $degree;
   //tu constructor recibe los datos al instanciar la clase
   public function __construct($name,$email,$biography,$degree){
   $this->name = $name;
   $this->mail =$email;
   $this->biography = $biography;
   $this->degree = $degree;
   }

    public function altaUser()
    {

        $stmt = parent::$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles(name, email, biography, degree) VALUES(:name, :mail, :biography, :degree)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $this->mail);
        $stmt->bindParam(":biography", $this->biography);
        $stmt->bindParam(":degree", $this->degree);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

esto es una idea de como seria el MVC.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, seguí te recomendación, no me marca errores pero no hace el alta

Comment: @AlfredoPaz aca ya hace falta un poco mas de información, por ejemplo tu clase conexión. Oh puedes asegurarte de que todo este bien simplemente imprimiendo por pantalla las variables en el archivo `controller`

Comment: gracias ya lo hice funcionar con tu respuesta, me estaba equivocando con algunos nombres, aceptaré tu respuesta @Yo Albert

Comment: Excelente respuesta, era justo lo que había que hacer.

Comment: @A.Cedano he aprendido mucho de usted, me tomare la libertad de comentarlo por aca!

Comment: @YoAlbert ya somos 2 que compartimos esa opinión